# Select dinámico en tabla dinámica y evento

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, laravel

estoy creando una tabla dinámica con ajax y a la vez, estoy llenando un select dinamico dentro de esa tabla pero necesito obtener el id del objeto de la BD que traigo. Es decir, el TD con nombre ID. Pero no consigo obtenerlo.

El fragmento de código con el cual intento sacar el estado y el código es este, el estado si lo he conseguido, lo que no es el ID.

```
// EVENTO SI CAMBIA EL SELECT DE ESTADO DE INCIDENCIA EN MOSTRAR INCIDENCIAS
            $(".estado").on("change", function(){
                var incidencia = $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text();
                var estado = $(this).find('option:selected').val();

                //actualizarEstado(estado, incidencia);
            });
```

Cabe destacar que también este select dinámico tiene un evento para comprobar cuando cambia y ahí es donde necesito obtener el id y el value del select.

Una vez que he obtenido los dos valores, los envio a la función que hace una nueva petición para actualizar el estado

Un saludo y gracias de antemano

**EDICIÓN**

Había que acceder al padre del elemento y para ahcer eso, se usa la función closest('tr') en este caso

```
// EVENTO SI CAMBIA EL SELECT DE ESTADO DE INCIDENCIA EN EL HOME DEL USUARIO

$(".estadoIncidencia").on("change", function(){
    // se usa closest para acceder al elemento padre de donde estamos generando el evento.
    var incidencia = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text();
    var estado = $(this).find('option:selected').val();


    actualizarEstado(estado, incidencia);
});
```

Comment: Deberías compartir un modelo de la data y la tabla con el select, porque yo veo el jquery y desde mi perspectiva el jquery esta bien y deberia funcionar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Había que acceder al padre del elemento y para ahcer eso, se usa la función closest('tr') en este caso

```
// EVENTO SI CAMBIA EL SELECT DE ESTADO DE INCIDENCIA EN EL HOME DEL USUARIO

$(".estadoIncidencia").on("change", function(){
    // se usa closest para acceder al elemento padre de donde estamos generando el evento.
    var incidencia = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text();
    var estado = $(this).find('option:selected').val();


    actualizarEstado(estado, incidencia);
});
```